# Java: Counting output from a random variable?

Tags: java

In this program after rolling a die "x" amount of times (userInput) I'm wanting to count the number of times each number occurs.

I tried making an else if that would add one to each random number occurrence but it only seems to work with the last random number, maybe it's because the if isn't in the while loop? I'm not sure how I would add the ifss and else ifs in the while loop... Perhaps I'm over-complicating this

```
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times a 6 sided die " +
            "should\nbe rolled");
    Random r = new Random();
    int numberOfRolls = userInput.nextInt();
    int randomRoll;
    int timesRolled = 0;

    if (numberOfRolls <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Nope, that's below zero");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    do {
        timesRolled++;
        randomRoll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println(randomRoll + " was rolled");
    }
    while (numberOfRolls > timesRolled);

    int numberOne = 0;
    int numberTwo = 0;
    int numberThree = 0;
    int numberFour = 0;
    int numberFive = 0;
    int numberSix = 0;

    if (randomRoll == 1)
    {
       numberOne ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 2)
    {
        numberTwo ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 3)
    {
        numberThree ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 4)
    {
        numberFour ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 5)
    {
        numberFive ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 6)
    {
        numberSix ++;
    }
    System.out.println(" One: " +numberOne+ "\n Two: " +numberTwo+ "\n Three: " +numberThree+
            "\n Four: " +numberFour+ "\n Five: " +numberFive+ "\n Six: " +numberSix);
}
```

**The output is:**

```
> Enter the number of times a 6 sided die should
be rolled
3
2 was rolled
5 was rolled
1 was rolled

 One: 1
 Two: 0    
 Three: 0
 Four: 0
 Five: 0
 Six: 0
```

Comment: And have you tried putting your logic **in the loop** where you actually perform the rolls? After you roll your dice, how many numbers will be "up"?

Comment: Moving the if condition into the while loop is correct. Make sure to move your variable declaration above your while loop as well. Also consider using a switch statement: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/switch_statement_in_java.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need your big if/else block inside your do/while loop that actually does the rolling.  The reason you are only getting 1 out is that when the do/while exits, it is only able to check the most recent value of `randomRoll`.  All other values have been overwritten by the last one and that data is lost.

Reorder it to look like this:

```
int numberOne = 0;
int numberTwo = 0;
int numberThree = 0;
int numberFour = 0;
int numberFive = 0;
int numberSix = 0;
do {
    timesRolled++;
    randomRoll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println(randomRoll + " was rolled");
    if (randomRoll == 1)
    {
       numberOne ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 2)
    {
       numberTwo ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 3)
    {
       numberThree ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 4)
    {
       numberFour ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 5)
    {
       numberFive ++;
    }
    else if (randomRoll == 6)
    {
       numberSix ++;
    }
}
while (numberOfRolls > timesRolled);
```

Edit: I really like Aelexe's suggestion to use it as as switch instead, so here is what that would look like:

```
//note that I'm shortening things a bit to save a little typing.  
//I don't have a Java compiler on the computer I'm at but I think I can get this right from memory.
int one, two, three, four, five, six;
one = two = three = four = five = six = 0;
do
{
   timesRolled++;
   randomRoll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
   switch(randomRoll)
   {
   case 1:
      ++one; break;
   case 2:
      ++two; break;
   case 3:
      ++three; break;
   case 4:
      ++four; break;
   case 5:
      ++five; break;
   case 6:
      ++six;
   }
} while(numberOfRolls > timesRolled);
```

Edit 2: Because I like cricket_007's suggestion as well, here is how that'd look:

```
// making this length 7 to avoid off-by-1 indexing issues
// even though they are easy to fix this is conceptually easier
// this just lets index 0 go to waste, its not like we need to save 4 bytes that badly
int[] counters = new int[7];
do
{
   timesRolled++;
   randomRoll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
   counters[randomRoll]++;
} while (numberOfRolls > timesRolled);
//printing
for(int i = 1; i < counters.length; i++)
{ 
   System.out.printf("Rolled number %d %d times", i, counters[i]);
   //I think my format string is right?  someone fix it if it isn't.
}
```

Comment: By the way, the default value for `int`s in Java is 0, so you don't need to initialize it.

Comment: @CacheStaheli It has been a while since I've done Java, but doesn't the compiler stop you if you try to `++` (or any other math operation) an uninitialized variable?

Comment: Not that I've ever seen.

Comment: Hm.  Maybe I'm mixing it up with another language then.  Or maybe I'm just in "overly cautious" mindset since I've been writing C for the last few weeks.

Comment: @CacheStaheli I just ran `public static void main(String[] args) { int x; x++; System.out.print(x); }` on https://www.compilejava.net/ and it gave me the "error: variable x might not have been initialized" error that I expected it to.  This default value thing might be compiler/compiler flag specific, but is beyond the scope of the OP's question either way.

Comment: Personally, I would use an array... One line for all cases. `rolls[randomRoll - 1]++`

Comment: @cricket_007 that is a better solution, I was trying to mimic the OP's original structure.  I might as well add that to my answer though.

Comment: Awesome thank you fellows! I appreciate the help, we haven't learned arrays yet in my java class so that is actually new to me!

Comment: @ChrisM happy to help.  If this answers your question, click the checkmark to accept this answer and close your question .

Answer (score 1):

This is how you code should look like:

```
    int randomRoll = 6;
    int  timesRolled = 0;

    int numberOfRolls = 8;

    int numberOne = 0;
    int numberTwo = 0;
    int numberThree = 0;
    int numberFour = 0;
    int numberFive = 0;
    int numberSix = 0;

    Random r = new Random();


    while (numberOfRolls > timesRolled ){
        timesRolled++;
        randomRoll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println(randomRoll + " was rolled");
        if (randomRoll == 1)
        {
            numberOne ++;
        }
        else if (randomRoll == 2)
        {
            numberTwo ++;
        }
        else if (randomRoll == 3)
        {
            numberThree ++;
        }
        else if (randomRoll == 4)
        {
            numberFour ++;
        }
        else if (randomRoll == 5)
        {
            numberFive ++;
        }
        else if (randomRoll == 6)
        {
            numberSix ++;
        }
        System.out.println(" One: " +numberOne+ "\n Two: " +numberTwo+ "\n Three: " +numberThree+
                "\n Four: " +numberFour+ "\n Five: " +numberFive+ "\n Six: " +numberSix);
    }
```